# Printing on specific parts of the terminal

Tags: c++, terminal, printing

So for my university homework we are supposed to make a simple game of a `2D map` with entities etc.
So I've figured a way of printing a map through it's dimensions and text formatting yet in our lessons it wasn't mentioned how we print on specific parts of the terminal. I've checked same questions but can't seem to get a solution.

Here is the code I use to print the map and make it's array. `BLUE_B,STANDARD_B,OUTLINE and GREEN_B` are declared above for the sake of color enrichment. Also IF POSSIBLE I don't want to use OS specific commands unless it's completely necessary. I use VS Code for Windows, compile with g++ on **WSL Ubuntu-20.04**.

```
for (int row = 0; row < i; row++) {
  cout << OUTLINE "##";
  for (int column = 0; column < j; column++) {
    int n = rand() % 10; // According to "rand()"'s value we print either green, blue, or trees
    if (n >= 3) { // We've assigned more values to green, in order to be more possible to be printed
      cout << GREEN_B "  "
      STANDARD_B;
      map[row][column] = 1;
    } else if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
      cout << BLUE_B "  "
      STANDARD_B;
      map[row][column] = 0;
    } else if (n == 2) {
      int tree = rand() % 2;
      cout << TREES "<>"
      STANDARD_B;
      map[row][column] = 0;
    }

  }
  cout << OUTLINE "##"
  STANDARD_B << endl;
}

for (i = 0; i < j + 2; i++) { // Bottom map border printing
  cout << OUTLINE "##"
  STANDARD_B;
}
```

Comment: You need to know the capabilities of the terminal in order to position code.  For example a teletype is a terminal that has very restricted set of commands for positioning the cursor.  There is a VT100 set of commands that are popular.  You could also review `ncurses` library.

Comment: Positioning characters on a terminal is not part of the C++ standard.  Positioning is terminal dependent, so you'll have to tell us which terminal you are targeting.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm using the terminal interface provided by VS Code and use WSL Ubuntu there. I'm not familiar with different terminal versions (I mean their difference in capabilities). Probably targetting a Unix-Linux based terminal if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you might be looking for [iomanip](https://cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/). It is just one way of doing it. You can use [setw](https://cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) and [setfill](https://cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/) to position different text in different areas. You can set different options for different outputs.

Answer (score 0):

To move the text cursor to a specific line and column you need a “gotoxy”-style function.

Here is something that will work on both **Linux terminals** and the **Windows Terminal**. (It will *not* work on **Windows Console** without additional initialization help.)

```
#include <iostream>

const char * CSI = "\033[";

void gotoxy( int x, int y )
{
  std::cout << CSI << (y+1) << ";" << (x+1) << "H";
}
```

Coordinates are (0,0) for the UL corner of the terminal. Here is a working example of use:

```
// continuing from above

#include <string>

int main()
{
  // Clear a 40 x 10 box
  for (int y = 0;  y < 10;  y++)
  {
    gotoxy( 0, y );
    std::cout << std::string( 40, ' ' );
  }
  
  // Draw our centered text
  gotoxy( 14, 5 );
  std::cout << "Hello there!";
  
  // Go to bottom of box and terminate
  gotoxy( 0, 10 );
  std::cout.flush();
}
```

#### For your game

I suggest you move the cursor to HOME (0,0) and draw the *changed* parts of your gameboard each frame.

<sup>I suppose that if you are on a local computer and your gameboard is relatively simple, you *could* probably get away with a complete redraw each frame...</sup>

Are you sure there is no professor-supplied macro or command to move the cursor home? (...as he has supplied magic macros to change the output color)?

Comment: I used your answer and modified it a bit to the requirements and use it for the case of a bigger that **20x20** map. Thank you! As for the professor-supplied macro he suggested system() type commands such as `(pause), ("clear")` and I try to avoid them as much as possible and I had created a function using `SetCursorPosition()` but that required **windows.h** and all of our projects are tested on Linux machines.

Comment: Also an edit for the last comment as I can't edit it. The output coloring was done by me the professor didn't really get into detail on how we print it.